# Uri(getString(R.string.link.mp3)) in broadcasg reciever

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, getstring, android-media3

I have created a fragment and **brodcastreciever.I** want to initialize exoplayer and its mediaitem from uri.broadcastReciever.I need to setUri by using `getString(R.string.text)`